# sudo npm -g sails -> install error

Tags: node.js, npm, sails.js

I have tried to install sails on my Mac (Mavericks) but I am getting an error message during the install process.

Here my console log:

```
...
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash._basecreate
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash._shimkeys
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash._basecreate

> ws@0.4.31 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually installing fine - it just looks like there's an error.

It's running the command `node-gyp rebuild` and [redirecting all errors to a file named `builderror.log`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/818284/1216976).

Comment: So what do I need to do? Thanks

Comment: Thats the content of the builderror.log

`gyp http GET http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.28/node-v0.10.28.tar.gz
gyp http 200 http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.28/node-v0.10.28.tar.gz
gyp http GET http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.28/SHASUMS.txt
gyp http GET http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.28/SHASUMS.txt
gyp http 200 http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.28/SHASUMS.txt
gyp http 200 http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.28/SHASUMS.txt`

Comment: Have you tried it?  Is it working?  There aren't any errors in `builderror.log`

Answer (score 0):

Those 304 statuses (instead of 200 ok) is just npm saying that those files are unchanged and doesn't need to download them again.

Your sails installation went ok. Now you can use "sails lift" to start your server.